# Number of seconds to date conversion

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data set where one of the columns is sales date. Don't know why, but R converts it to numeric why performing any operation. I would like to convert it back to `POSIXct` date format in R. To do the same, I am using below code, but getting an unexpected result

```
 x= as.Date(1448208000, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "3967028-10-31"
 x= as.POSIXct(x,"%Y-%m-%d")
```

I am not good with dates format in R and would appreciate any kind of help in this regard.

Comment: `1448208000` is the number of seconds since the unix epoch, and is the numeric representation of a `POSIX` object. you probably want `as.POSIXct(1448208000, origin = "1970-01-01")`

Comment: What operations exactly are converting it back to numeric?

Comment: @MrFlick, I am pivoting data using `sqldf`, the output is converting it to numeric. Thank you!

Comment: @SymbolixAU, it's working now. Thank you!

Comment: A word of caution; watch out for timezones.

Comment: try the lubridate package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1448208000` is the number of seconds since the unix epoch, and is the numeric representation of a POSIX object. To convert it back to `POSIXct` you want

```
as.POSIXct(1448208000, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

---

You'll also probably want to ensure the timezone is correct too; see the difference between these two commands

```
as.POSIXct(1448208000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
# [1] "2015-11-22 16:00:00 UTC"

as.POSIXct(1448208000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "Australia/Melbourne")
# [1] "2015-11-23 03:00:00 AEDT"
```