# Date-time to numeric and backwards

Tags: r

**Dates/Times in R**
I have this date: "2016-10-29 15:00:00" and i want to convert it to numeric and backwards to the same date and time i had. I used this to convert it to numeric:
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-10-29 15:00:00"))
How i can get back my initial date and time?

```
    "2016-10-29 15:00:00"
    as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-10-29 15:00:00"))
   1477771200
```

I obtain that answer, but i need it back to "2016-10-29 15:00:00". What should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060854/numeric-to-date-conversion-in-r

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as.POSIXct()` on your number, but you also need to supply the `origin` and (probably) `timezone`

```
as.POSIXct(1477713600, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "Australia/Melbourne")
"2016-10-29 15:00:00 AEDT"
```

The `as.POSIX()` comamnd needs to know from which reference point the numeric starts. This is usually the Unix Epoch of 1970-01-01

---

The documentation for `?as.POSIXct` shows the useage for a numeric object

> ### S3 method for class 'numeric'
>
> as.POSIXlt(x, tz = "", origin, ...)

showing you need to supply the origin

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
as.POSIXct(yourNumeric)
```

Where yourNumeric is your number.

Comment: Have you tested this?