# Is ifelse() coercing datetimes to numeric?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data frame containing datetimes (in this case generated with `lubridate`, but I don't think that's relevant here) and some dt components extracted. I then want to conditionally alter the datetimes and re-extract those components.

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(magrittr)
> library(lubridate)
> df = data_frame(
    dt.utc = dts,
    date.utc = date(dt.utc),
    hour.utc = hour(dt.utc))
# A tibble: 20 x 3
                dt.utc   date.utc hour.utc
                <dttm>     <date>    <int>
 1 2017-01-01 01:00:00 2017-01-01        1
 2 2017-01-02 02:00:00 2017-01-02        2
 3 2017-01-03 03:00:00 2017-01-03        3
 4 2017-01-04 04:00:00 2017-01-04        4
 5 2017-01-05 05:00:00 2017-01-05        5
 6 2017-01-06 06:00:00 2017-01-06        6
 7 2017-01-07 07:00:00 2017-01-07        7
 8 2017-01-08 08:00:00 2017-01-08        8
 9 2017-01-09 09:00:00 2017-01-09        9
10 2017-01-10 10:00:00 2017-01-10       10
11 2017-01-11 11:00:00 2017-01-11       11
12 2017-01-12 12:00:00 2017-01-12       12
13 2017-01-13 13:00:00 2017-01-13       13
14 2017-01-14 14:00:00 2017-01-14       14
15 2017-01-15 15:00:00 2017-01-15       15
16 2017-01-16 16:00:00 2017-01-16       16
17 2017-01-17 17:00:00 2017-01-17       17
18 2017-01-18 18:00:00 2017-01-18       18
19 2017-01-19 19:00:00 2017-01-19       19
20 2017-01-20 20:00:00 2017-01-20       20
```

If I use `replace()`, I have a problem where the replacement items have to be only as large as the number of replacements (rather than being as large as the original datetimes). So instead I'm using `ifelse()`:

```
> df %<>%
  mutate(
    dt.new = ifelse(
      hour.utc %% 2 == 1 & date.utc > '2017-01-10',
      dt.utc + hours(1),
      dt.utc))
```

This correctly combines from `dt.utc` and its modified version. But it comes with an unexpected problem: `ifelse` appears to be coercing the result to `numeric` somewhere along the way:

```
> df
# A tibble: 20 x 4
                dt.utc   date.utc hour.utc     dt.new
                <dttm>     <date>    <int>      <dbl>
 1 2017-01-01 01:00:00 2017-01-01        1 1483232400
 2 2017-01-02 02:00:00 2017-01-02        2 1483322400
 3 2017-01-03 03:00:00 2017-01-03        3 1483412400
 4 2017-01-04 04:00:00 2017-01-04        4 1483502400
 5 2017-01-05 05:00:00 2017-01-05        5 1483592400
 6 2017-01-06 06:00:00 2017-01-06        6 1483682400
 7 2017-01-07 07:00:00 2017-01-07        7 1483772400
 8 2017-01-08 08:00:00 2017-01-08        8 1483862400
 9 2017-01-09 09:00:00 2017-01-09        9 1483952400
10 2017-01-10 10:00:00 2017-01-10       10 1484042400
11 2017-01-11 11:00:00 2017-01-11       11 1484136000
12 2017-01-12 12:00:00 2017-01-12       12 1484222400
13 2017-01-13 13:00:00 2017-01-13       13 1484316000
14 2017-01-14 14:00:00 2017-01-14       14 1484402400
15 2017-01-15 15:00:00 2017-01-15       15 1484496000
16 2017-01-16 16:00:00 2017-01-16       16 1484582400
17 2017-01-17 17:00:00 2017-01-17       17 1484676000
18 2017-01-18 18:00:00 2017-01-18       18 1484762400
19 2017-01-19 19:00:00 2017-01-19       19 1484856000
20 2017-01-20 20:00:00 2017-01-20       20 1484942400
```

It doesn't appear to be before the combination happens, because wrapping the second and third arguments to `ifelse` in `ymd_hms` or similar doesn't affect the result.

One clue might be in [the `ifelse` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/ifelse): 'The mode of the answer will be coerced from logical to accommodate first any values taken from yes and then any values taken from no.'

Does that mean that the test argument (which is `boolean`) gets coerced but is ending up `numeric` instead of `POSIXct`? Do I just need to coerce the result back to `POSIXct` myself by wrapping the entire `ifelse` function in something?

Comment: this is expected behaviour of `ifelse`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6669237/5977215) for a detailed explanation, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45806213/5977215) for how to convert numeric to `POSIXct`.

Comment: Thanks—looks like I could've broadened my search terms before asking. Glad to hear `if_else` behaves differently!